# Undo Changes with collection of images

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a undo functionality to a picture box by saving the image right before the paint take place into a array or something. I tried  with List but i get the same image all the time, with Image List the size is to small for my porpoises. What are the best practices for saving undo data or how can i store images into memory right before every paint take place? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clone the image contents every time. I think you are adding always the reference of the image to the list.

If you want to get undo functionality done properly have a look at the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Another way would be to calculate the difference of the original image and the image after the operation and then store the difference to save memory.

Comment: Thank you. I created a instance of a bitmap every time I saved and works great. I will try looking into a more elegant way to do this and remove the restrictive savings of 5 bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Many paints will take place on the same image.  Windows fires the Paint event whenever part of the control needs to be repainted.  Like when you drag another window across the PB.  Or minimize and restore the form.

In other words, Paint doesn't tell you that the image changed.  You'll need to derive your own class from PictureBox and override the Image property.  The setter will be called when the image is changed.

Comment: The save is conditioned by a bool value so is done just when is need it.